# how to update layer hierarchy with react-leaflet

Tags: react-leaflet

i'am using a context state variable to store a array of `WMSTileLayer`objects. The order of the array shall be the same order as the created leaflet layers.

If i reorder one existing WMSTileLayer to a new position (new state of tile as a new fresh array with new order) the order of the leaflet layers are still the same.

Adding and removing works fine.

```
const MapViewerCore = (): ReactNode => {

  const { tiles, updateOrAppendWmsTree } = useMapViewerContext()


  const displayMap = useMemo(() => (
    <MapContainer
      center={[51.505, -0.09]}
      zoom={2}
      scrollWheelZoom={true}
      style={{ flex: 1, height: '100%', width: '100%' }}
    >
      {...tiles}

    </MapContainer>
  ), [])

  return (
    <Box sx={{ ...style }}>
      {displayMap}
    </Box>
        
  )
}
```

How is it possible to reorder the layer order of the leaflet context?

I also tried to remove all leaflet layers if the tiles state variable change:

```
const context = useLeafletContext()
...

useEffect(()=>{
  context.eachLayer((layer) => context.removeLayer(layer))

},[tiles])
```

But this will result in empty layers (all layers are removed and not appended)

Answer (score 0):

related to the [hint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52260535) of automatic deconstructing react components, i found a workaround by

```
 <WMSTileLayer
        key={(Math.random() + 1).toString(36).substring(7)}
 />
```

The React components with the old keys are removed by react from the dom and by this event handling also from the leaflet context.

This will always create new Layer instances inside the map context.